# Audit all does not capture truncate

Tags: oracle, audit, truncate

I want to capture truncate and drop operations on my table.

So i executed the following:

```
SQL> select name, value from v$parameter where name like '%aud%';

NAME           VALUE
----           -----
audit_trail    DB


SQL> create table audit_test (id number);

Table created.


SQL> audit all on audit_test by access;

Audit succeeded.

SQL> create table audit_test (id number);

Table created.


SQL> audit all on audit_test by access;

Audit succeeded.


SQL> truncate table audit_test;

Table truncated.
```

And the truncate does not exists in the dba_audit_Trail...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 (+1) possible reasons:

0 - `AUDIT ALL` does not audit `TRUNCATE` operations. Use `AUDIT TABLE BY ACCESS;`

1 - You perform the above as SYS user. Actions performed by SYS are
    audited into files, under the location of `audit_file_dest`

2 - [AUDIT (Traditional Auditing)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/AUDIT-Traditional-Auditing.htm#SQLRF01107)

> Track the issuance of SQL statements in subsequent user sessions. You
>   can track the issuance of a specific SQL statement or of all SQL
>   statements authorized by a particular system privilege. **Auditing
>   operations on SQL statements apply only to subsequent sessions, not to
>   current sessions.**

Try it in a new session.

Comment: 1- this is not a sys user. I take your 1st suggest and try it, but still didn't worked. After i added the last idea with the new session it worked! If the truncate execute from exist session it just doesn't work. Thank you very much!